# 'Messaging System' with more than 1 user in conversation, build from scratch in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, private-messaging

So I am trying to implement a messaging system in my application, and I have no intention on using any of the gems. I've seen most of them and I'm able to use them. But for learning sake, I want to learn how it works and build one from scratch and be able to customize it how I want it.

I have looked around for tutorial but there isn't any tutorial or anything concrete information except for; this -> http://.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html, but unfortunately link is down or this -> [Rails threaded private messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405457/rails-threaded-private-messaging), but I still cant wrap my head around everything.

So hope this thread will serve as a point of reference for others.

So based off this thread  [Rails threaded private messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405457/rails-threaded-private-messaging), this is what I have including the columns definitions.
But I'm having problem wrapping my head around the logic on adding multiple users in a conversation. The way that I see this:

1. Click on send a message, which will trigger a new conversation object
2. Add a subject, and select users that I want in the conversation <-- this is where it gets cloudy
3. at the bottom without of that same form without any ajax, I guess I could render message form which will submit the text?

Ok so how do I put multiple user ids in the conversation table users_id column? There is a suggestion to use 'act_as_taggable' gem from this thread -> [Rails threaded private messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405457/rails-threaded-private-messaging) comes in? If so, how is the database is going to know that it should select all these user in a certain conversation object.

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
 #columns -> :subject, :users_id

  has_many :messages
  has_many :participants
  has_many :users, :through => :participants
end



class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
 #columns -> :conversation_id, :sender_id, :read

  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
 #columns -> :user_id, :conversation_id

  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :participants
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `conversations` table should **not** have a user_id/users_id column as you have setup a many to many relationship in this case.

You can add users to a conversation by doing something like:

```
@conversation.users << @user
@conversation.save
```

Or in a form it would be something like:

```
<%= form_for Conversation.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, User.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}, {multiple: true} %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You can get users in a conversation with `@conversion.users`.

Also, your user model should be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participants
  has_many :conversations, through: :participants
end
```